# Iterating over vector returns same object

Tags: c++, vector

I'm attempting to learn C++ by creating a small maze generator. To facilitate this, I store a list of Cell(), along with x and y values inside a vector in Maze() (some other pieces of information are included below for completeness, but aren't relevant).

The cells are stored in a vector, with X and Y value of the cells being determined and passed in to each cell as it is created.

The problem I'm having is that each cell appears to have the same x and y values populated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
vector<Cell*>  Maze::cells;
int Maze::width;
int Maze::height;

Maze::Maze(int w, int h)
{
    /* Set width and height */
    width     = w;
    height    = h;

    /* These variables keep track of our position in the maze as we generate it */
    int scan_w = 0;
    int scan_h = 0;

    /* Continue looping until we've visited all cells */
    /* Offset by one because the width starts at 1 while the scan is zero-based */ 
    for (int i = 0; i <= (width * height); i++)
    {
        cells.push_back(new Cell(scan_w,scan_h));

        cout << scan_w << "/" << scan_h << endl;
        scan_w = (i % w);
        if (scan_w == 0)
        {
            scan_h++;
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i <= cells.size(); i++) 
    {
        cout << "[" << cells[i]->x << ", " << cells[i]->y << "]  " << &cells[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the relevant parts of the Cell class

```
int         Cell::x;
int         Cell::y;

Cell::Cell(int location_x, int location_y)
{
    x = location_x;
    y = location_y;
}
```

The output of this code (truncated for brevity) is:

```
Maze maze = Maze(50, 25);

0/0
0/1
1/1
2/1
3/1
4/1
5/1
6/1
7/1
8/1
9/1
...
40/25
41/25
42/25
43/25
44/25
45/25
46/25
47/25
48/25
49/25
[49, 25]  0x632f30
[49, 25]  0x632f38
[49, 25]  0x632f40
[49, 25]  0x632f48
[49, 25]  0x632f50
[49, 25]  0x632f58
[49, 25]  0x632f60
[49, 25]  0x632f68
...
```

Here are my assumptions:

- Based on the output, scan_w and scan_h are being incremented as intended (as if reading a table from left to right, top to bottom).
- Based on the flow control documentation/tutorial, my understanding is that the first for loop is properly moving from one element of **cells** to the next.
- Based on the [documentation for vector's push_back member](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/), I'm assuming that it is properly inserting the reference to each newly created cell into the vector.
- Based on the [documentation for the [] operator for vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/), my understanding is that if I access cell[0] and cell[1], I will be accessing different objects (this is confirmed by printing the object's address, as above).

So I'm having trouble understanding why the value of x and y for each cell is 49 and 25, respectively, when any given cell is supposed to be incremented in alignment with scan_w and scan_h.

Lastly, here are a couple of things I considered:

- The for loop may be reading the same object (disproved by printing the address of the object).
- This may be an issue of scope. I'm used to Python, so my presumption is that scope works the same way, but I'm not well enough versed in C++ to know if that's accurate.
- This may have something to do with the way Vectors operate (more or less disproven by the documentation on the [] operator).
- The output may be deceptive/the scan_ incrementation code may be buggy. This is the most likely scenario, but I haven't been able to spot anything off yet. Possibly a short break and fresh eyes may reveal something here.

Comment: The code for the Cell class is missing!

Comment: Apart from anything else, your <= operators should be < operators.

Comment: @koalo Whoops - added!

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code posted (bugs and all).

Comment: The way you are defining your x and y variables above your constructor - are they static members? If so, that's your (main) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the blue, considering how you have formatted the code for the Cell class. Could it be that x and y are defined static (otherwise you would not write "int Cell:x;" anywhere...)? Then the case is clear, because that is the nature of members defined static. The solution would be to just remove the static keyword.

Comment: This was it! 

Will update the question with corrected code.

Comment: @Exsomet do not update the question to contain the answer. It muddies the Flow of the Question and Answer format.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (width * height); i++)
```

This is iterating one too many times. If, for example, both width and height are 10, this will iterate with i set to the range of 0 to 100 ***inclusively***, or 101 cells, instead of 100.

The next problem is that computation of `scan_w` and `scan_h` is unnecessarily complex. This should be a trivial calculation, using simple math, and also fixing the iteration bug at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++)
{
    int scan_w = i % width;
    int scan_h = i / width;
    cells.push_back(new Cell(scan_w,scan_h));
}
```

Another bug is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= cells.size(); i++)
```

Same problem as the first bug. On the last iteration, `i` will be equal to `cells.size()`, and `cells[i]` will not exist, resulting in undefined behavior.

Again, the iteration should be corrected to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++)
```

You can start by fixing these problems yourself, then checking to see if the results match your expectations, or if there are still other problems.

Comment: Fixed these - looks like I maybe need to brush up on a couple of the basics. Thanks!